# How to add Status column at the end

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a "Status" column based on the comparison of "Name" and "FirstName" columns as well as the "Salary" and "Sal" columns. If the corresponding pairs match, the "Status" should be "Pass" else "Fail"

Sample Data:

```
src_data
ID | Name    | Salary | EMAIL
1  | Sweta   | 1000   |abc
2  | Manish  | 2000   |def
3  | Priyanka| 3000   |ghi
```

tgt_data

```
EMP_ID | FirstName | Sal   |Email
1      | Sweta     | 1000  |abc
2      | Manish    | 3000  |def 
3      | Priyanka  | 4000  |cde
4      | Naveen    | 5000  |ghi
```

output currently i am getting

```
ID     | Name     | FirstName     | Salary     | Sal
1      | Sweta    | Sweta         | 1000       | 1000
2      | Manish   | Manish        | 2000       | 3000 
3      | Priyanka | Priyanka      | 3000       | 4000
```

Output i want

```
ID     | Name     | FirstName     | Salary     | Sal   |Status
1      | Sweta    | Sweta         | 1000       | 1000  |Pass
2      | Manish   | Manish        | 2000       | 3000  |Fail
3      | Priyanka | Priyanka      | 3000       | 4000  |Fail
```

Below code i tried

```
import pandas as pd

class Excel:
    def __init__(self, src_file_name, src_sheet_name, src_pk, src_cols_to_compare, tgt_cols_to_compare, tgt_file_name, tgt_sheet_name, tgt_pk, target_excel):
        self.src_file_name = src_file_name
        self.src_sheet_name = src_sheet_name
        self.src_pk = src_pk
        self.src_cols_to_compare = src_cols_to_compare
        self.tgt_cols_to_compare = tgt_cols_to_compare
        self.tgt_file_name = tgt_file_name
        self.tgt_sheet_name = tgt_sheet_name
        self.tgt_pk = tgt_pk
        self.target_excel = target_excel

    def highlight_cells(self, row):
        styles = [''] * len(row)
        pk_cols = [col for col in row.index if col in [self.src_pk, self.tgt_pk]]

        for i, col in enumerate(row.index):
            if i % 2 == 1 and col not in pk_cols:
                src_col = col
                tgt_col = row.index[i + 1]
                if row[src_col] == row[tgt_col]:
                    styles[i], styles[i + 1] = 'background-color:lightgreen', 'background-color:lightgreen'
                elif pd.isnull(row[src_col]) or pd.isnull(row[tgt_col]):
                    styles[i], styles[i + 1] = 'background-color: yellow', 'background-color: yellow'
                else:
                    styles[i], styles[i + 1] = 'background-color:lightcoral', 'background-color:lightcoral'

        return styles

    def Read(self):
        src_df = pd.read_excel(self.src_file_name, sheet_name=self.src_sheet_name)
        tgt_df = pd.read_excel(self.tgt_file_name, sheet_name=self.tgt_sheet_name)

        result = src_df.merge(tgt_df, how='inner', left_on=self.src_pk, right_on=self.tgt_pk)
        result_columns = [self.src_pk] + [col for pair in zip(self.src_cols_to_compare, self.tgt_cols_to_compare) for col in pair]
        result = result[result_columns]
        result.style.apply(self.highlight_cells, axis=1).to_excel(self.target_excel)

comparator = Excel(
    src_file_name='source.xlsx',
    src_sheet_name='Sheet1',
    src_pk='ID',
    src_cols_to_compare=['Name', 'Salary'],
    tgt_cols_to_compare=['FirstName', 'Sal'],
    tgt_file_name='target.xlsx',
    tgt_sheet_name='Sheet1',
    tgt_pk='EMP_ID',
    target_excel='result.xlsx'
)

comparator.Read()
```

can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].  Where exactly is your code going wrong? What have you done to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

class ExcelComparator:
    def __init__(self, src_file_name, src_sheet_name, src_pk, src_cols_to_compare, tgt_cols_to_compare, tgt_file_name,
                 tgt_sheet_name, tgt_pk, target_excel):
        self.src_file_name = src_file_name
        self.src_sheet_name = src_sheet_name
        self.src_pk = src_pk
        self.src_cols_to_compare = src_cols_to_compare
        self.tgt_cols_to_compare = tgt_cols_to_compare
        self.tgt_file_name = tgt_file_name
        self.tgt_sheet_name = tgt_sheet_name
        self.tgt_pk = tgt_pk
        self.target_excel = target_excel

    def highlight_cells(self, row):
        styles = [''] * len(row)
        pk_cols = [col for col in row.index if col in [self.src_pk, self.tgt_pk]]

        for i, col in enumerate(row.index):
            if i % 2 == 0 and col not in pk_cols:
                src_col = col
                tgt_col = row.index[i - 1]  # Adjusted to get the previous column

                if row[src_col] == row[tgt_col]:
                    styles[i], styles[i - 1] = 'background-color:lightgreen', 'background-color:lightgreen'
                elif pd.isnull(row[src_col]) or pd.isnull(row[tgt_col]):
                    styles[i], styles[i - 1] = 'background-color:yellow', 'background-color:yellow'
                else:
                    styles[i], styles[i - 1] = 'background-color:lightcoral', 'background-color:lightcoral'

        return styles

    def calculate_status(self, row):
        for i in range(len(row.index) - 1, 0, -2):
            src_col = row.index[i]
            tgt_col = row.index[i - 1]

            if row[src_col] != row[tgt_col]:
                return 'Fail'

        return 'Pass'

    def read_and_compare(self):
        src_df = pd.read_excel(self.src_file_name, sheet_name=self.src_sheet_name)
        tgt_df = pd.read_excel(self.tgt_file_name, sheet_name=self.tgt_sheet_name)

        result = src_df.merge(tgt_df, how='inner', left_on=self.src_pk, right_on=self.tgt_pk)
        result_columns = [self.src_pk] + [col for pair in zip(self.src_cols_to_compare, self.tgt_cols_to_compare) for col
                                         in pair]

        result = result[result_columns]
        result['Status'] = result.apply(self.calculate_status, axis=1)

        result.style.apply(self.highlight_cells, axis=1).to_excel(self.target_excel)


# Example usage
comparator = ExcelComparator(
    src_file_name='source.xlsx',
    src_sheet_name='Sheet1',
    src_pk='ID',
    src_cols_to_compare=['Name', 'Salary'],
    tgt_cols_to_compare=['FirstName', 'Sal'],
    tgt_file_name='target.xlsx',
    tgt_sheet_name='Sheet1',
    tgt_pk='EMP_ID',
    target_excel='result.xlsx'
)

comparator.read_and_compare()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

class ExcelComparator:
    def __init__(self, src_file_name, src_sheet_name, src_pk, src_cols_to_compare, tgt_cols_to_compare, tgt_file_name,
                 tgt_sheet_name, tgt_pk, target_excel):
        self.src_file_name = src_file_name
        self.src_sheet_name = src_sheet_name
        self.src_pk = src_pk
        self.src_cols_to_compare = src_cols_to_compare
        self.tgt_cols_to_compare = tgt_cols_to_compare
        self.tgt_file_name = tgt_file_name
        self.tgt_sheet_name = tgt_sheet_name
        self.tgt_pk = tgt_pk
        self.target_excel = target_excel

    
    def highlight_cells(self, row):
    styles = [''] * len(row)
    pk_cols = [col for col in row.index if col in [self.src_pk, self.tgt_pk]]
    start_highlighting = False

    for i, col in enumerate(row.index):
        if col == self.src_pk[-1]:
            start_highlighting = True
            continue

        if start_highlighting and i % 2 == 1 and i < len(row.index) - 1:
            src_col, tgt_col = col, row.index[i + 1]

            if row[src_col] == row[tgt_col]:
                styles[i], styles[i + 1] = 'background-color:lightgreen', 'background-color:lightgreen'
            elif pd.isnull(row[src_col]) or pd.isnull(row[tgt_col]):
                styles[i], styles[i + 1] = 'background-color:yellow', 'background-color: yellow'
            else:
                styles[i], styles[i + 1] = 'background-color:lightcoral', 'background-color:lightcoral'

    return styles


    def calculate_status(self, row):
        for i in range(len(row.index) - 1, len(self.src_pk)-1, -2):
            src_col = row.index[i]
            tgt_col = row.index[i - 1]
            if ps.isnull(row[src_col]) or pd.isnull(row[tgt_col]):
                return "Fail"
            elif row[src_col] != row[tgt_col]:
                return 'Fail'

        return 'Pass'

    def read_and_compare(self):
        src_df = pd.read_excel(self.src_file_name, sheet_name=self.src_sheet_name)
        tgt_df = pd.read_excel(self.tgt_file_name, sheet_name=self.tgt_sheet_name)
        src_pk = tuple(self.src_pk) if isinstance(self.src_pk,list) else self.src_pk
        tgt_pk = tuple(self.tgt_pk) if isinstance(self.tgt_pk,list) else self.tgt_pk

        result = src_df.merge(tgt_df, how='inner', left_on=src_pk, right_on=tgt_pk)
        result_columns = [list(src_pk) + [col for pair in zip(self.src_cols_to_compare, self.tgt_cols_to_compare) for col
                                         in pair]

        result = result[result_columns]
        result['Status'] = result.apply(self.calculate_status, axis=1)

        styled_result = result.style.apply(self.highlight_cells, axis=1)
        styled_result.to_excel(self.target_excel,index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your `highlight_cells` method and add a new column

```
def highlight_cells(self, row):
    styles = [''] * len(row)
    pk_cols = [col for col in row.index if col in [self.src_pk, self.tgt_pk]]

    for i, col in enumerate(row.index):
        if i % 2 == 1 and col not in pk_cols:
            src_col = col
            tgt_col = row.index[i - 1]
            if row[src_col] == row[tgt_col]:
                styles[i], styles[i - 1] = 'background-color:lightgreen', 'background-color:lightgreen'
                row['Status'] = 'Pass'
            elif pd.isnull(row[src_col]) or pd.isnull(row[tgt_col]):
                styles[i], styles[i - 1] = 'background-color: yellow', 'background-color: yellow'
                row['Status'] = 'Fail'
            else:
                styles[i], styles[i - 1] = 'background-color:lightcoral', 'background-color:lightcoral'
                row['Status'] = 'Fail'

    return styles
```

Moreover, in the `Read` function, add the following line to initialize the new column:

```
result['Status'] = ''  # Initialize the 'Status' column
```

Comment: Hi Marco, Thank you i tried this but its throwing error: index 6 is out of bound for axis 0 with size 6

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code and I think it's a just an index problem.. could you try again? Let me know ;)

Comment: Hey Marco, I tried, but the 'Status' column is showing blank for every row and also, the every background cell appears in light coral color.

Comment: Hey Marco, I've got the solution and posted it here. However, I'm facing an issue when supplying multiple columns as keys. I'm getting an error.: Unhashable list Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I add one more answer with a possible solution to your last problem, let me know if it works and in case we clean the thread (question, answers and comments) @SwetaRawani

Answer (score -1):

The error `Unhashable list` is likely due to using a list `[col for pair in zip(self.src_cols_to_compare, self.tgt_cols_to_compare) for col in pair]` as a key in the result_columns.

To resolve this issue, you can convert the list of column names to a tuple, which is hashable. You can modify the line creating result_columns as follows:

Try this modified part in the `read_and_compare` method:

```
result_columns = [self.src_pk] + [col for pair in zip(self.src_cols_to_compare, self.tgt_cols_to_compare) for col in pair]
result_columns = [tuple(pair) if isinstance(pair, list) else pair for pair in result_columns]

result = result[result_columns]
```

Comment: yes Marco this is working Thanks

Comment: Hi Marco, need help in highlight_cells() method is not working as expected when i have odd number of columns as a primary key while its working as expected for even what modification i have to do so that it can handle both scenario. I added my answers, could you please check.